# ReWrite Rule for Dbname as common subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

Could someone please help me with the following re-writes for Apache
I want the results to be:

> domain.com/ (Landing search page for which DB username belongs to)
>
> domain.com/db1/ (For index login page to db1 where db1 can be any other db name)
>
> domain.com/db1/accounts/ (Once logged in)
>
> domain.com/db1/admin/ (Another page once logged in)

Please help me with a `url re-write` if it is possible to do this...

I have something like this but it's not working:

`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /(.*)/$ /index.php?dbname=$1

RewriteRule /(.*)/account/$ /account.php?dbname=$1
`

Thank you

Regards
Johan

Comment: What have you achieved so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid rewriting calls to /

Just present the login form in index or in whatever other page you want.

Then

This block tells the server to allow rewriting, to stick with existing files and directories and only rewrite what does not "exist", and that you will be rewriting from /

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
```

then your rules

```
RewriteRule ^db([0-9]+)$            index.php?dbname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]
RewriteRule ^db([0-9]+)/account$    index.php?admin=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
RewriteRule ^db([0-9]+)/admin$      index.php?admin=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
```

This is assuming that after login you will be sending him to

```
https://www.yoursite.com/db1 
https://www.yoursite.com/db1/account 
https://www.yoursite.com/db1/admin
```

for instance

Comment: Great Thank you, but my dbnames are not just 1-10 they can be anything for example cx001, how would i do that?

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` letter, lower and uppercase; numbers; hifens and underscores...

Comment: you could also redirect everything to index.php as you were doing, then explode the url and handle them like some real front controler...

Comment: Hi great thanks, but can I not do this to re-write any first level to dbname:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$        index.php?dbname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L] (Doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Also by your answer, it seems like it is only rewriting account/dbname not dbname/account....

Comment: Thank you for the assist, I was able to get my final rewrite rules working the way i wanted it to:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$         index.php?dbname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/accounts/$ account.php?dbname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]`

Comment: @johan but... what if we try to go to site.local/ujgksjdg ?
Get to send a 404 header I guess?